# Tracking in chapter titles with titlesec

Tags: spacing, chapters, titlesec

I've been trying to add tracking (letter spacing) to my chapter titles with `titlesec`, but to no avail.

I'm using `fontspec` and `XeTeX`, so `microtype` isn't available to me. Another post said this can be done with `\addfontfeatures{LetterSpace=XXX}`, but the tracking remains the same.

I'm a TeX newbie, so I'm not sure where the error is in my MWE.

Here's an image and the code I used to produce it:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fmtcount}

\newcommand{\ttlspc}{\addfontfeatures{LetterSpace=20}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{}
    {\ttlspc\filcenter\normalfont\Large\bfseries Part\ \Numberstringnum{\thechapter}}
    {.2cm}
    {\ttlspc\normalfont\Large\itshape\filcenter}

\begin{document}
\chapter{TheNameOfTheChapter}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

What can be done to solve my problem?

Comment: your example produces a warning saying the font feature is ignored here: `* fontspec warning: "addfontfeatures-ignored"
* 
* \addfontfeature(s) ignored; it cannot be used with a font that wasn't
* selected by fontspec.`  are you using fontspec to specify a font in your real document?

Comment: Ah @DavidCarlisle, I apologize. This wasn't a complete example of what I'm actually doing in my document. I do declare a font with `\setmainfont` in my actual document, I just didn't include it here. Egreg's solution worked. I made a rookie mistake. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems; one is minor and is in the fact that you *must* declare `\setmainfont` in order to apply `\addfontfeatures`.

The second problem is due to the fact that you're overriding `\ttlspc` by saying `\normalfont after it.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fmtcount}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman} % or whatever font

\newcommand{\ttlspc}{\addfontfeatures{LetterSpace=20}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{}
    {\filcenter\normalfont\ttlspc\Large\bfseries Part\ \Numberstringnum{\thechapter}}
    {.2cm}
    {\normalfont\ttlspc\Large\itshape\filcenter}

\begin{document}
\chapter{TheNameOfTheChapter}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't use letter spacing unless you're doing all caps or caps and small caps: see http://webtypography.net/2.1.7

Here's a possibility with spaced small caps:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\setmainfont{Hoefler Text}
\newfontfamily{\romanspaced}{Hoefler Text}[
  LetterSpace=15
]

\newcommand{\ttlspc}{\addfontfeatures{LetterSpace=20}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{}
    {\filcenter\normalfont\romanspaced\Large\scshape Part\ \Numberstringnum{\thechapter}}
    {.2cm}
    {\normalfont\normalsize\romanspaced\scshape\filcenter}

\begin{document}

\chapter{The Name Of The Chapter}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I actually like the look of smallcaps in my document more than mixed case.

Comment: @egreg; May I know where from where the tag `\romanspaced` comes from? Please advise...

Comment: @MadyYuvi I defined it myself with `\newfontfamily`

Comment: @egreg Much thanks for your prompt reply...